# Powershell Loop | Moving files and creating shortcuts

Tags: loops, powershell

I've created a list of "top files" I need to migrate to a shared drive using the following command

```
$Files= Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Users\User\Documents\ -filter "*.txt" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select FullName | select -First 10
```

The output of which looks like:

```
> echo $Files
FullName
--------
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc1.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc2.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc3.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc4.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc5.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc6.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc7.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc8.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc9.txt
C:\Users\User\Documents\doc10.txt
```

The issue I'm having is that for every file, I need to do two actions:

1. Move it to a set location
2. Create a shortcut, using the same filename and point it to the new location.

If this was bash, a simple 'for i in..." would work, but I'm lost when it comes to PowerShell

Additionally, when referencing it, there seem to be additional characters added to the list, such as:

```
@{FullName=C:\Users\User\Documents\doc1.txt}
```

This seems to break anything I've been able to do thus far as it's unable to handle the extra (incorrect) characters)

To make the request more clear: What is the best method for looping through each item and doing 'x' action?

Comment: foreach($file in $Files) { write-Host $file.FullName }

Comment: I think that'll work nicely. Sorry for the easy question